# What is the type, 'function' in Python?

Tags: python, nameerror

I am using python 3, and am wondering what 'function' is.

For example, here I create a function `a` and print its type.

```
def a():
    pass

print(type(a))
```

I get `<class 'function'>`.

When I try to use the type `function`, however, I get a `NameError`.

Here is an example:

```
function
```

or

```
fplaceholder=function
```

both give me a `NameError`, saying `function` is not defined.

What exactly is `function`, then?

Comment: I believe it is `types.FunctionType`

Comment: In CPython, functions are implemented in C as [`PyFunctionObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/function.html#c.PyFunctionObject), which is exposed to the programmer as [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType).

Comment: @Vladimir Vilimaitis and @wkl, can I assume that `types.FunctionType` will behave as the nonexistent function in most cases?

Comment: @user18798042 - What do you mean by "nonexistent function"? There isn't such a thing. There is `None`, which is the general NULL object in python. But all variables and containers have to reference an object, even if that object is `None`.

Comment: @tdelaney, I was making a joke. It has to do with the fact that you get a `NameError` when attempting to reference `function` in Python (meaning it isn't defined).

Comment: @user18798042 - Its a type, not a function object. You can build your own function object via `fplaceholder = types.FunctionType(...)` but you also need to supply the initialization paramters. Perhaps just a `code` object that you could get via `compile(...)`.